# How to keep iOS keyboard opened while alert showing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, ios9

I have a textfield in my iOS application and sometimes I need to show alert messages (`UIAlertView`) for different reasons (for example, too many characters etc.).

When I show the alert the keyboard hiding. How can I keep keyboard opened while alert message is showing? Or maybe I missed something?

The way I use alerts:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                                        message:@"Too many characters."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
```

Answer (score 2):

> I need to show alert messages (`UIAlertView`) for different reasons (for example, too many characters etc.)

This would be terrible UX, do it a different way such as showing a validation label near to the text field.

Something like what is suggested in [this article](https://dhawaldawar.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/uitextfield-validation-ios/):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is something Apple introduced with iOS 8 and it makes sense as well. When alert is shown on screen you do not want user to get diverted with things like keyboard.

However, if you still want to show it then when user tap on `UIAlertView` button you can call `[textfield becomeFirstResponder]` on your text field or text view.

Answer (score 0):

Call `[textfield becomeFirstResponder]` after your `[alert show]` just like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                                        message:@"Too many characters."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
[textfield becomeFirstResponder]
```